# How to make a form shrink to a smallest possible size?

Tags: .net, winforms

How to make a form shrink to a smallest possible size Windows.Forms?

There was a pack() method in Swing that woked well but if I make all the components and a form itself AutoSise = true I get a dot (one pixel dot) on the screen.

Comment: have you tried setting just the form Autosize to true?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to define a 'smallest possible size', use the `Form.MinimumSize` property.